# The block 'xyz/If Action Normal/In1' has a discrete sample time that does not match the sample time 0 of the If block 'abc' controlling its execution

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've run into the following error message from Simulink:

> The block 'xyz/If Action Normal/In1' has a discrete sample time that does not match the sample time 0 of the If block 'abc' controlling its execution

My solver configuration is variable step/auto, and the environment could be seen at the end of this post.

I tried a few methods:

1. try to locate the error by replacing/comment out blocks;
2. try to change the port driving if-action block;
3. try to remove all discrete blocks;

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: The message is telling you that the `If` block and the `If Action` subsystems that it feeds, must have the same sample times.  In your case they currently do not.

Answer (score 0):

This error is hidden behind a Matlab known bug. Basically, when I tried to add a rate transition to make the same time consistent. The system crashed.

The crash is because of a known Matlab bug. A zero-holder needs to be added following unit delay blocks. After this, I could add rate transit block without model crashing.